# How to access property with leading numbers in name

Tags: javascript, json

```
var jsonJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://wowtoken.info/snapshot.json");
var json = Utilities.jsonParse(jsonJSON.getContentText());

var max24 = json.NA.formatted.24max;
```

I'm sure my code is sloppy but, I'm getting "Missing ; before statement." from the bottom line. It goes away when I remove the '24', but the [source](https://wowtoken.info/snapshot.json) itself has '24max'.

Is there a way to have javascript ignore the 24 after the period? Or are the top two lines of code wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the numbers in front of the object names during parsing, you can also access the object's property like you would access an array element like so.

`json.NA.formatted["24max"]`

JavaScript variables must begin with a letter, `$` or `_`. That is the reason why you are getting an error instead.